# MTOUCH: error MT0034 Xamarin.iOS and Catel

Tags: xamarin, catel

I am getting this error when I try to compile my Xamarin.iOS app. I am referencing Catel.MVVM and Catel.Fody.

Any idea what to do?

```
MTOUCH: error MT0034: Cannot include both 'monotouch.dll' and 'Xamarin.iOS.dll' in the same Xamarin.iOS project - 'Xamarin.iOS.dll' is referenced explicitly, while 'monotouch.dll' is referenced by 'Catel.MVVM, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Comment: Try to remove the Xamarin.iOS.dll reference from your project.

Comment: Yip. Was the first thing I tried... made it worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your project parts uses the UnifiedAPI (Xamarin.iOS.dll) and another one uses the Classic API (monotouch.dll). They can not be both part of the project.

You goal should be to use the UnifiedAPI/ Xamarin.iOS.dll instead of the old monotouch assembly because with the new one you are able to get your app in the store. Xamarin Studio is able to convert your project to the UnifiedAPI. I am not sure but take a look under Project > "Convert to UnifiedAPI" or something like that.

Comment: Will do, sounds promising.

Comment: It would seem that the project is already using Unified API... is it not the case that the Catel.MVVM should not use monotouch.dll?

Comment: I took a look at the source on github and it looks like Catel.MVVM.Xamarin.iOS is not updated to the UnifiedAPI. I looked at the Release 4.3.0 branch which seems to be the latest.

Comment: Ah. That could explain it. Thanks. I will contact the developer of Catel and add to this question when I have more info.

Comment: Would be glad if you mark my answser as the one that fits, if it was helpful to you.